# Responsive Background Image/Image Element That Will Resize In Mobile Version

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to solve how image will stay in its position even if the screen will reduce it size.

Like in this website:
https://www.milkable.me/ (Notice the top section. The "png" images will maintain its position even the screen will get small.)

Do you guys know the solution for this? I'm just trying to make this 2 png images to be responsive and stay in it's position even the screen reduce.

Let me know. Any help will gladly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can someone have a solution for this?

Comment: To be honest I don't really know, what you are asking for. Which pngs? Please describe your problem clearer, provide some code samples. If you want something like website from link, why don't you just inspect it with any browser using programmer tools? It is all there.